# Zipping two observables - filtering one observable with input from the other first.

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I am trying to use rxJava and retrofit to combine two RESTful calls and return a single combined object that I can then use to update an android app.  I think I should be using zip, but the issue I have is that I need to filter the second observable based on the first observable.

My two restful calls look like this

1. Is a listing call and automatically filters out objects - returning only configured devices.
2. Is a status call and does not filter anything.

So call #1 will return a set of objects like this:

- Device: ID=2, Name="Bar"
- Device: ID=3, Name="Baz"

However, call #2 will return all objects even if they are not configured and looks like this:

- Device: ID=1, Status=0
- Device: ID=2, Status=75
- Device: ID=3, Status=100

What I am trying to do is return a combined object that takes the devices from call #1 and decorates them with the status from call call #2. Both calls will always return the objects in sorted order by ID.

The combined output should be a List of objects looking like this:

- Device: ID=2, Name="Bar", Status=75
- Device: ID=3, Name="Baz", Status=100

Answer (score 0):

Let me give this a try, I'm still learning Rx so take this with a grain of salt:

```
Observable.zip(api.firstCall(), api.secondCall(),
 (firstResult, secondResult) 
-> { Observable.from(secondResult).filter({ firstResult.containsId(it) }).toList(); })
.subscribe(callback);
```

Basically this is what I think should happen: we get our results after both calls are executed. I assume we get a list as secondResult, so we use `.from()` to divide the list into observables. Then we filter them out (the check .containsId() has to be implemented by you). After all is done we convert the result back to a list.